# Invalid expression term 'int' - Casting object to primitive data type

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a class that is a dictionary of `<string, string>`, which is a collection of "variables", identified by their keys. I use MySQL to store them, so when I load/save them, I do it as a string, because there is no "generic data type" for sql.

When I want to retrieve a value, I need to cast it to whatever object I need. So what I did is:

```
protected object GetVariable(string key, Type type = null)
    {
        string result;

        this.Character.Variables.TryGetValue(key, out result);

        if (type == null)
        {
            return result;
        }

        object value = Convert.ChangeType(result, type);

        return value;
    }
```

Basically, you pass the key and the type you want to convert to. If it's null, it will return the default (string) immiediately. If it's not, it will attempt to convert to a primitive data type and return it. So, I tried calling:

```
int a = GetVariable("test", int);
```

However, when I tried to compile this file using CodeDomProvider, It said:

```
Invalid expression term 'int'
```

Why's that? How can I fix that?

I'm using C#.

Comment: Why don't you use a generic type parameter for your method like `protected T GetVariable<T>(string key)` (with `return (T) Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));` at the end of the method)? Then you can call it like `int a = GetVariable<int>("key")` or `bool b = GetVariable<bool>("key")`.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass in a type using the [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) operator. This will get you the actual `Type` instance of the `int`:

```
int a = GetVariable("test", typeof(int));
```

Optionally, you could change your code to use generics, as suggested in comments:

```
protected T GetVariable<T>(string key)
{
    string result;

    this.Character.Variables.TryGetValue(key, out result);

    if (result != null)
    {
        return Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
    }
    else
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3717565: Need more help?